# Error .NET Compact Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Al Abrir un nuevo proyecto en Visual Studio C# me manda esta advertencia y al querer debugear ... me lo pasa a error

> Advertencia   2   This project requires .NET Compact Framework v4.5.1,
>   which is not installed on this machine.   proyect1

Ya instale nuevo framework y sigue mandando ese error

```
Advertencia 5
```

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.ServiceModel.targets"
>   no se puede volver a importar. Ya se importó en
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Targets
>   (377,5)". Lo más probable es que se trate de un error al crear la
>   compilación. Se omitirá esta importación.
>   [c:\users\sistemas2017\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\FacturacionCSharp\FacturacionCSharp\FacturacionCSharp.csproj

Ya movi los targeds de la carpeta pero siguio marcando el mismo error

]

Comment: que version de Visual studio estas utilizando ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini visual studio 2012

Answer (score 3):

Recuerda que `.NET Compact Framework` esta discontinuo, por lo que no esta presente en versiones mas nuevas del `Visual Studio`

Debes tener instalado y abrir el proyecto con `Visual Studio 2008`, dos referencias sobre este tema:

[Visual Studio 2010 + Windows Mobile + .NET Compact Framework](https://geeks.ms/jmtorres/2009/06/03/visual-studio-2010-windows-mobile-net-compact-framework/)

[.NET Compact Framework with Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646027/net-compact-framework-with-visual-studio-2010)

ya con VS2010 no hay mas soporte

Comment: Si, pero al momento de querer trabajar con un sistema de facturación en c# me manda es error, eso es lo que se me hace extraño, mas porque es windows form